# How to close colorbox with a button

Tags: jquery, button, iframe, colorbox

I use colorbox iframe:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"85%", height:"65%", fastIframe:false});      
});
```

On my second page I have a button, where I want to post some image and after the action I want to  close the frame window.

```
<input type="button" id="selected" value="the_button" />
```

and the script

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#selected").bind('click',function() {

        window.setTimeout(function() 
        {
            $.colorbox.close(); 
        }, 2500);

        alert('hi');

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#selected").bind('click',function() {

        window.setTimeout(function() 
        {
           parent.$.colorbox.close();
        }, 2500);


    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ares, but I try this and don't help.
I try also 

$("#selected").click( function() {
  parent.jQuery.colorbox.close(); return false;  
});

It show me error "permission denied to access property 'jquery' "

Comment: If I comment "parent.jQuery.colorbox.close(); return false;"
and put "alert('hi');" it's show right, no error.

Comment: What html tag #selected is?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and I used `$('#cboxClose').remove();`  it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your HTML:

```
<a href="#" onClick="$.colorbox.close();">Close Colorbox</a>
```